# Invalid column name 'rootQuestion_QuestionID' while reverse engineering in visual studio .net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a problem mapping a relationship
while reverse engineering in visual studio .net

I use inheritance:

```
public class Quiz : Component  
{
    public QuizQuestion rootQuestion { get; set; }
    public override String getType() { return "quiz"; }
}
```

the property 'rootQuestion' is not specified in the motherclass, it only exists in the subclass

'Quiz' doesn't exist as a table in my sqlserver database(only the QuizQuestions and Component table exists in the database,( my teacher told me to do it like this for
the java part of this project).
But I want the subclass Quiz to have a property rootQuestion that refers to quizRootQuestion in my database
so here's what i did:

```
public class QuizMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Quiz>        
{
    public QuizMapper()               
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.ComponentID);
        this.HasOptional(c => c.rootQuestion)
            .WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("quizRootQuestionID"));     

    }
}

public class QuizQuestionMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<QuizQuestion>
{
    public QuizQuestionMap()
    {
        // Properties
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.HasKey(t => t.QuestionID);
        this.ToTable("QuizQuestions");
        this.Property(t => t.QuestionID).HasColumnName("questionID");
    }
}
```

I get this error when i'm trying to run in my browser:
**Invalid column name 'rootQuestion_QuestionID'.**

Tables in my database:

*Component:*
componentId
quizRootQuestionID
TypeId(=discriminator)

and

*QuizQuestions*
questionID
question

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Check out this [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) on implementing table-per-hierarchy in code first.

Comment: thanks, i hope this helps, been searching for quite a long time now :p

Comment: nice link, the only problem is that it doesn't show the mapping with fluent API of those specific propertys in the subclass :(